# You said you’ll bring some from home, right?

Tags: tense, backshifting

> You said you’ll bring some from home, right?

> You said you would bring some from home, right?

What's the difference between the two sentences? The only difference is 'll vs would

Comment: If the time when addressee was expected to "bring some" is *in the past* at time of speaking, the first version (with ***will***) is extremely unlikely, if not nonsensical. But quite apart from that, we *normally* "backshift" in contexts like this *(He **said** his name **was** Smith, You **said** you **would** bring them)*.

Answer (score 2):

> You said you’ll bring some from home, right?

> You said you would bring some from home, right?

Let's say we are planning for a party, which is not yet due.  #1 would be appropriate.

If the party is already over, and now you are discussing about certain past agreed arrangements, #2 would be appropriate.

Comment: But *would* can also be used of future events to be polite, as when making a request or suggestion, which could apply here.

Answer (score 2):

In practical usage

> You said you’ll bring some from home, right?

is confirming the listener will bring food from home to some future event as a matter of fact.

> You said you would bring some from home, right?

sounds a bit accusatory in that the listener failed a previous commitment to bring food from home.  It depends very much on which word has the emphasis.